# Linq performance issue in loop

Tags: performance, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an `Asp.Mvc5` web site, we have somme performance issues, here is our model:

We have a survey which contains a list of sections, each section has a list of subSections, each subSections has a list of questions. A subsection can be present in several sections (we need another table to stock the order of subSection in a section).

A question has QuestionSubSection which determines the order of the question in the given subSection (a question can be present in several subSecton).

We have a list of companies, each company has a list of answers.
Our web site display the list of answers for a given company in the order defined by the model above.

After analysis of the code I figure out that the following line needs 2 seconds to execute:

```
foreach(var section in Survey.ordredBy(s => s.Order)
 {
  foreach(var subSection in section.SebSections.ordredBy(s => s.Order)
  {
   foreach(var question in subSection .Questions.ordredBy(s => s.Order)
   {
    //this query cause a perfermance issues
    var answer = company.Answers.Where(c => c.QuestionId == questionId);
   }
  }
}
```

What do you suggest for me to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the posted code, I have to assume that you already have a value for `questionId`.  If this is true then all of the `foreach` statements are totally superfluous (not needed) because none of the `var` values from the `foreach` statements is used anywhere.  Kill the `foreach` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are running one query per question in the survey.  If you have lots of questions, that may take a while.

Instead, query all of the answers you are going to need in one request to the database, e.g. something like

```
var allAnswers = company.Answers.Where(c => c.SurveyId == surveyId);
```

Hopefully the answers know (have a reference to) what question they are for, the questions know what subsection they are for, etc.

Comment: but i have to respect the order of answer defined in the survey

Comment: Use OrderBy to order by section, then sub-section, then question.  Still a single query.